# Estimate the average number of customers in a M/M/1 queueing system during a certain time period

Tags: poisson-distribution, estimation, queueing-theory, exponential-distribution

Let the M/M/1 queue with parameter $\lambda$ and $\mu$ start at state $n_{0}$ at the time $0$, the question is to estimate the average number of customers in the system during a certain time period T.

My solution is to use a very naive approach by doing a simulation of M/M/1 queue for the time T. Here is how I solve it.

The probability for the queue to move to the next state is 
\begin{equation}
p=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}
\end{equation}
The time for the queue to stay in one state is an exponential distribution random variable with parameter $\lambda + \mu$.
My method is like this:

1. Generate a random variable $\Delta t_0$ with exp($\lambda + \mu$), which is representing the stay time for the queue at state $n_0$;
2. Generate a uniform random variable $p_0$ between $0$ to $1$, if $p_0 < p$, let the state $n_1$ be $n_0 + 1$, else be state $n_0 - 1$;
3. Repeat 1 and 2 until the time period T runs out, say the last state to be $n_k$ (i.e. $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \Delta t_k = T$);
4. The average number of the customers in the queue for the time period T is equal to 
   \begin{equation}
   \bar{n} = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k} \Delta t_kn_k}{\sum_{i=0}^{k} \Delta t_k}
   \end{equation}

Please help me check if this solution is correct. Also, I'm wondering that if there is any analytical solution, if so, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your approach is correct and sensible. Steps 1 and 2 need to change if the state is $n=0$. In this case there are only arrivals and the time until a jump is exp($\lambda$). Step 3 needs to take into account some truncation of $\Delta t_k$ because the sum will never equal exactly $T$.

Comment: @QQQ Thank you. I also realized these two problems. I also want to know that if there exists any analytical solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no analytical solution for the non-stationary expected queue length. There are approximations (fluid or diffusion). Another approach without simulation is numerically solving the Kolmogorov backward differential equations: $p'(k)=\mu p(k+1)+\lambda p(k-1)-(\lambda+\mu)p(k)$.